# How does the .net SqlConnection object check that a connections string is syntactically valid?

Tags: .net, sql, connection-string

> ```
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection foo = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
>        foo.ConnectionString = "Data Source=myServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"; // exception thrown on this line
> ```

If I declare a new `SqlConnection` object in my .net code and then set the `ConnectionString` field to a syntactically invalid connection string, an exception is thrown.

I have checked several times that if the connection string is semantically incorrect (eg. invalid server name, wrong password), no exception is thrown.

What logic is the `SqlConnection` object using to validate the connection string at this point?  I've tried to no avail to answer this question using RedGate Reflector.

Comment: I'm not really interested in Reflector per se so much as I am interested in just knowing what the class is doing to verify my connection string.

Answer (score 2):

The validation logic is in the internal `SqlConnectionString` class's single-string constructor, which it hits via a rather circuitous route.

`SqlConnection.ConnectionString`'s set accessor calls:

```
SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(string);              // Which calls ->
DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(string, ...); // Which calls ->
SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(...);       // Which calls ->
SqlConnectionString(string) // Constructor - take a look at this for details
```

(Notice that the final call is **not** to the single-string constructor for `SqlConnection` - it's constructing an instance of *a different class*, `SqlConnectionString`.)

Comment: The constructor that takes a string for an argument is just a single line that says `this.ConnectionString = connectionString`.  That clashes with your answer.

Comment: @Rising Star - you're looking at the wrong class. I'm talking about the constructor for `SqlConnectionString`, **not** `SqlConnection`. I've updated my answer to emphasize that.

Answer (score 0):

Connection strings should be a straightforward list of name=value pairs, separated by semicolons (;). What exception are you getting?

If you're using Reflector to try to work out how your string gets parsed, you might find it easier to look at `System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder`. SQL Server's own `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` inherits from this class.